# AS3: Access object property or function on extended class that isn't in the super class

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-builder, flashdevelop

If I have three classes:

```
public class Example {
   public function Example () {

   }
}

public class ExtendedExample extends Example {
   public function func ():void {
        //here is what this class does different that the next
   }
   public function ExtendedExample () {

   }
}

public class AnotherExtendedExample extends Example {
   public function funct ():void {
       //here is what this class does, and it is differente from ExtendedExample
   }
   public function AnotherExtendedExample () {

   }
}
```

You can see that the two last classes extend the first one, and both have the 'variable' property. In case that I have an instance of Example and I am sure it is also an ExtendedExample OR AnotherExtendedExample instance, is there some way to access the 'variable' property? Something like

```
function functionThatReceivesAnExtendedExample (ex:Example):void {
    if(some condition that I may need) {
        ex.func()
    }

}
```

Comment: Move 'variable' to the 'Example' class.

Comment: won't fix my problem because I'm not dealing with a var, but with a function. I just eddited my question so that you understand

Comment: I'm assuming the 't' on 'funct' is a typo. The answer's nearly the same then: move 'func' to 'Example' and override it in the subclasses.

Comment: yes, that is the answer, override, thank you! I'm writing an answer to my own question with this answer, so that others can find it easily. would you like to do it yourself so that I can choose your answer?

Answer (score 1):

If the variable is used in some of your subclasses, but not in all of them, and you haven't defined it in the parent class, you can still try to access it. I'd suggest some quick casting:

```
if (ex is AnotherExtenedExample || ex is ExtendedExample)
{
    var tmpex:ExtendedExample = ex as ExtendedExample;
    trace (tmpex.variable);
}
```

You can also cast it to a dynamic Object type and attempt to access the property in a try..catch block. I'd recommend using casting like above where the logic is easier to follow.

If the variable is used in all subclasses, just define it in the parent class and give it a specific value in each subclass.

Comment: Since you switched your question to deal with a function, my example still works, but you'd need to override the parent function and define it for each extended class. The casting method works just as described.

Comment: I can't access it because I'm not dealing with dynamic Objects, and I'm also avoiding to use them because they are slower

Answer (score 1):

@Lucas change your code as below code

```
function functionThatReceivesAnExtendedExample (ex:Example):void {
    if(ex is ExtendedExample) {
        (ex as ExtendedExample).func()
    } else if(ex is AnotherExtendedExample)
    {
        (ex as AnotherExtendedExample).funct() 
    }
}
```

hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

As RIAstar says in his comments, the most obvious way would be to make `Example` also have a `func` function, and override it in the sub classes.

Implementing an interface, instead of extending a base class, or doing both, could be another way to let `functionThatReceivesAnExtendedExample` call `func` on `ex` without caring what exact class the `ex` object is, and without the `Example` class having to implement a `func` function, as in your example. So something like this, building on your example code:

```
public class Example {
    public function Example () {

    }
}

public interface IFunc {
    function func():void;
}

public class ExtendedExample extends Example implements IFunc {
    public function func ():void {
        //here is what this class does different that the next
    }
}

public class AnotherExtendedExample extends Example implements IFunc {
    public function func ():void {
        //here is what this class does, and it is differente from ExtendedExample
    }
}

function functionThatReceivesAnExtendedExample (ex:IFunc):void {
    ex.func()
}
```